# How do I call a shell script which calls python scripts from a different folder?

Tags: shell

Right now, I have `shellScript.sh` and `test_me.py` in a folder `ABC/def`. `shellScript.sh` calls `test_me.py`. I'm trying to call `shellScript.sh` from the ABC folder. So far, I keep on getting "No such file or directory" errors.

I've tried calling the python script from the shell script such as:

```
python /ABC/def/test_me.py
```

but this still gives me the same error.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Capitalization counts. The directory is `/home` most likely and not `/Home`.

Comment: Oh, it's not actually called Home! Sorry if that's unclear--I just made up a name. I'll change it in my question.

Comment: Then make sure you are getting that error on trying to run the python script and not on running the shell script or on the path in the shebang (`#!`) lines. How are you calling the shell script? Do other lines in the shell script work?

Comment: The error is: python: can't open file '/ABC/def/test_me.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory, so I'm pretty sure it's the python script.

Comment: And does that **exact** file path exist and does your user (or whoever is running the script) have access to that file and all the directories in that path?

Comment: Yeah, that exact file path does exist...I think the user should have access to all the files. I'm kind of new at all the permissions and stuff so I'm not entirely sure. I do know that everyone has access to the shell script.

Comment: What does `ls -l /ABC/def/test_me.py` as the user running the script output? What about `ls -ld /ABC/def` and `ls -ld /ABC`, etc. for the directories?

Comment: Okay, I've managed to fix it--apparently it was stored in a different folder than the one specified in the text editor? It was very confusing, and I'm still not sure why it's like this, but at least it runs now. Thanks for your guidance!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your home directory starts by a capitalize H, if it does not (which is highly probable) your script won't work.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is not in the path or filename, then it could be in the way you are executing the shellScript.sh:

```
./shellScript.sh
```

might fix it provided you have the proper execute bit set on the script file. If not, try this:

```
sh /proper/path/to/shellScript.sh
```

If that does not fix it, then try to cd to the directory in the script before the python line:

```
cd /to/proper/folder
python test_me.py
```

Comment: The shell script does run, it'll print out some test statements I wrote, just when it hits the python script it can't find the files.

Comment: What's in the python script?